# Property does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I created a Vue file like the code below.
By running `vti diagnostics` I see 2 errors: (I show you the first one, the other is for property name).

I'm pretty new to vue + typescript so I was wondering what I'm doing wrong.

```
Property 'code' does not exist on type 'never'.
   7 |     <ul v-if="categories.length > 0" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll">
   8 |       <template :key="index" v-for="(cat, index) in categories">
>  9 |         <div>{{ cat.code }} {{ cat.name }}</div>
     |                     ^^^^
  10 |       </template>
  11 |     </ul>
  12 |   </div>
```

```
<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    let categories = ref<BaseCategory[]>([]);

    const getBaseCategories = async () => {
      await store.getBaseCategories();
      categories.value = store.categories;
    };

    return {
      getBaseCategories,
      categories,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

my model is:

```
export interface BaseCategory {
  id: number;
  code: string;
  name: string;
}
```

the getBaseCategories are triggered from the Vue template like this

```
  <div style="background:red:color:white;" v-if="loading">bezig met laden</div>
  <div class="red" v-if="!loading">
    <div>total categories: {{ totalCategries }}</div>
    <button @click="getBaseCategories()" type="button">
      getBaseCategories()
    </button>

    <ul style="height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll">
      <template :key="cat.id" v-for="cat in categories">
        <div>{{ cat.code }} {{ cat.name }}</div>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

The code below is the how I build the store.

```
import {
  Module,
  VuexModule,
  getModule,
  Mutation,
  Action,
  MutationAction,
} from "vuex-module-decorators";

import api from "../../../../lib/api";
import store from "../../store";
import { IBaseCategory } from "../models";

@Module({
  dynamic: true,
  namespaced: true,
  name: "basecategories",
  store,
})
class BaseCategoryModule extends VuexModule {
  categories: IBaseCategory[] = [];

  @MutationAction
  async getBaseCategories() {
    const result = await api.get('/v1/basecombicategories');
    const data = result.data as IBaseCategory[];

    return {
      categories: data,
    };
  }
}

export default getModule(BaseCategoryModule);
```

Comment: Where do you trigger `getBaseCategories` ?

Comment: @JackYu: i've updated my code

Comment: where did you define the store and how do you import it?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim the code where I define the store is added

Answer (score 0):

```
// Here you say categories will be an array.
let categories = ref<BaseCategory[]>([]);

const getBaseCategories = async () => {
   await store.getBaseCategories();

   // here you treat categories as an object.
   categories.value = store.categories;

   // maybe this should be
   categories = store.categories;
};
```

Comment: that doesn't work because of `ref<BaseCategory[]>([]);` this is the new composition api https://composition-api.vuejs.org/#ref-vs-reactive

Comment: Then what would be the correct way to access the referenced value inside the template?

This `<template :key="cat.id" v-for="cat in categories">` or 
`<template :key="cat.id" v-for="cat in categories.value">` ?

Comment: ref automatically unwraps to the inner value, so we don’t need to append .value in the template

Answer (score 0):

According to the [async MutationAction === magic](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators#async-mutationaction--magic) in your used module. You should tell your action to mutate which state like following code (mark1).

```js
// ignore other codes .......
class BaseCategoryModule extends VuexModule {
  categories: IBaseCategory[] = [];

  // ========= mark1 =========
  @MutationAction({ mutate: ['categories'] })
  async getBaseCategories() {
    const result = await api.get('/v1/basecombicategories');
    const data = result.data as IBaseCategory[];

    return {
      categories: data,
    };
  }
}

export default getModule(BaseCategoryModule);
```

Comment: thx for your answer, I added this to my code. building / deploying everything works, but when I run `vti diagnostics` the errors still remain `Property 'code' does not exist on type 'never'.

Comment: Could you `console.log(result)` after `const result = await api.get('/v1/basecombicategories');`in your store? I think `result.data` might be a `null` or `undefined` value.

Comment: Or your `result.data` doesn't contain `code` in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable ... maybe I drunk to much :) There was another *.vue file with old code. I removed the old code and everything works perfectly. Shame on me !

Comment: i’m curious about adding mutate in store. What if you remove it and run with your new vue file?

Comment: if I replace @MutationAction({ mutate: ['categories'] }) with   @MutationAction then it behaves exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

I was having problem with state, and I was need to declare object properties.
like this

I had to change this

```
  state: () => ({
    training: {},
   }),
```

to this

```
 state: () => ({
    training: { id: '', name: '' },
  }),
```